# how to copy a value from float? to float, and put zero if the float? is null?

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I have this code :

```
StartPosLongitude = (object)time.StartPosition.Position.Long ?? 0
```

it does not compiles with error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'float'

StartPosLongitude is decladed like this : `float StartPosLongitude;`
time.StartPosition.Position.Long is returned by a wsdl and is of type float? and is null sometimes.

The error tells me I am trying to convert a object to a float, but that is not what I am doing.
In my opinion am trying to cast a float to an object.

So why does the compiler tells me something else ?
And what would be the proper way to do this, I need to put the value of `time.StartPosition.Position.Long` into `StartPosLongitude` but put 0 if `time.StartPosition.Position.Long` is null.

**EDIT**
time.StartPosition.Position.Long is of type **float?** not float

Comment: How can a float be null?  It can only be null if the type is nullable float (float?), surely

Comment: @fubo In the question you can find that it is type float

Comment: Just remove `(object)` cast (why is it there at all?)

Comment: If ```time.StartPosition.Position.Long``` is ```float```, it can't be ```null```. If you can have ```null``` in your data, it should be ```Nullable<float>``` (same as ```float?```).

Comment: Let me help you understand why you get the compiler error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'float'". You use the `(object)` cast to cast the right side of the line to type of `object`. You then pass this `object` to `StartPosLongitude` which seems to be of type `float`. You cannot do this, you cannot put an `object` in a `float` variable. If you remove the `(object)` cast, the error should go away.

Comment: @PJvG Well that makes perfect sense offcourse, I feel a bit stupid now. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think

```
StartPosLongitude = (object)time.StartPosition.Position.Long ?? 0
```

should be

```
StartPosLongitude = time.StartPosition.Position.Long.HasValue ? time.StartPosition.Position.Long.Value : 0f;
```

or

```
StartPosLongitude = time.StartPosition.Position.Long ?? 0f;
```

because `time.StartPosition.Position.Long` is type of `float?` - otherwise

> but put 0 if time.StartPosition.Position.Long is null

couldn't happen.

Comment: the compiler does not recognize .HasValue

Comment: It will be shorter to just do `StartPosLongitude  = time.StartPosition.Position.Long ?? 0`

Comment: @daniell89 expression `time.StartPosition.Position.Long ?? 0` is of type `float`, not `float?`, so nowhere here is assigning `float?` to `float`.

Comment: How could compiler not recognize `.HasValue`? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,712e7d0ea9003815

Comment: @Evk, Question was edited. StartPosLongitude is float but time.StartPosition.Position.Long  is float? But even if it was float you still can't compare it to null :)

Comment: @daniell89 you should just paste `float? test = 1; float result = test ?? 0;` in visual studio and see that it works, I think I cannot convince you just by explanations.

Comment: @fubo After restarting VS it recognized .HasValue. Dont know why but I sometimes need to do this

Answer (score 4):

You can do it just like this

```
StartPosLongitude = time.StartPosition.Position.Long ?? 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 StartPosLongitude = time.StartPosition.Position.Long != null ? (float)time.StartPosition.Position.Long : 0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention that **time.StartPosition.Position.Long** that is return by wsdl is float? type and **StartPosLongitude** is also float? type.

If you going to cast float to object it will return object. But **StartPosLongitude** is of float? type .So it generating and compilation error.

If you want to convert that float? to object and assign to **StartPosLongitude** variable .Then declare **StartPosLongitude**  as object type. Otherwise currently both variable is float? type.

Comment: No, StartPosLongitude is float not float?